# Is it good to store static data in db - C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have this problem and I don't know what is the best solution for it.

I have table called Employees and there is column called LastWork, this column should only have custom values I choose for example:

```
value 1
value 2
```

and I want the user to select the value from ComboBox control so I have 2 ideas for it but I don't know what is the best for it.

A - add these value to Combobox as string in Items property and store them as string in DB.

B - create separate table in my db called for example 'LastWork' with 2 columns 'LastWorkID', 'LastWorkName' and insert my values in it, and then I can add binding source control and I can use data bound items to store the id as integer in my main table and show the LastWorkName for users.

I prefer to use the B method because in some forms I have DataGridView control with edit permission, and I want to display Combobox in it instead of Textbox to select from these custom values.

I hope you understood my questions.

Comment: How static are they? Are they in essence constants? ie. "english names for weekdays"? Or will they change *sometimes*?

Comment: @Lasse, Take your example "English names for weekdays" and toss in internationalization. Suddenly they are no longer constants at all.

Comment: @Michael The english weekday names are still constant. I see your point though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally data normalization is a good thing, so I too would go with your option B.

By having a separate table and a foreign key relationship to it, you can enforce data integrity; easily get a list of all available (not just all selected) options; have a single place in which to change the text of an option (what if someone decides to call it "value one" instead of "value 1", for example?); and so on and so forth.

These might not be huge benefits in a small application and with only two possible options, but we all know that applications very often tend to grow in scope over time.

Comment: +1 for mentioning how much easier it is to standardize on data names because they are drawn from a central location.

Comment: thanks for helping me but my main idea was to store the LastWorkID value in the main table and use it to get the LastWorkName from the other table and display it so I don't need to use any foreign key relationship .

Comment: +1 for data integrity with the help of an additional lookup table. A nice addition to this kind of scenario is usual code automation on the middle layer by creating a similar `enum`. So developers don't repeat and sync those values every time they change the DB table: http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html

Comment: @SzamDev: I suggest you do force FK otherwise one may add invalid IDs. It doesn't cost you anthing but it will make a better DB design.

Comment: @SzamDev, any time you have a strictly definable relationship from one table to another, it's usually a good idea to define a foreign key to enforce it. You can always make the column allow NULL values and insert a NULL if, say, none of the available options are applicable - NULLs are a blessing in disguise, but sometimes they are indeed both useful and applicable.

Answer (score 1):

In a normalized database, your "option B" is usually the way to go because it eliminates duplicate data. It will potentially introduce an additional join into your queries when you need the name (and not just the ID), but it also allows you to rename lookup names easily without altering their underlying IDs.

For performance reasons, it's often a good idea to cache lookup values such as you describe in the business tier so that your lookup table is not hit over and over again (such as when building many rows of a grid).

Comment: If the table is that small (two small columns by two rows), chances are it will remain cached in RAM, so the performance hit should be minimal even if you end up with table scans.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling - True, unless the database was on a different machine (or even different network). Then latency could hurt performance regardless of SQL caching. Most applications I wrote have 50+ name/value tables in them, so I tend to write some sort of wrapper to guarantee that performance will never be an issue regardless of size or database location.

Comment: good point about latency. But that assumes that the business tier is on the same host as the application tier, otherwise you're pretty much back where you started.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling - agreed, if all the tiers are distributed then the cache(s) need to be located appropriately or an application design needs to be considered that only retrieves the needed data once.

Answer (score 1):

I would always save them in the db. If you have to localize your app, this helps alot. Additonally, it let you to apply the referential integrity checks of the database.